# Mongo 3.0.4 Unable to login

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have create a user in Mongo 3.0.4 and enable authentication, I can login in Mac but not in Ubuntu 14.04

This is how I followed process to enable authentication

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "mongoUser",
    pwd: "User123#@!",
    roles: [
      { role: "read", db: "trackuser" },
      { role: "readWrite", db: "trackuser" },
      { role: "dbAdmin", db: "trackuser" },
      { role: "dbOwner", db: "trackuser" }
    ]
  }
)
```

**auth=true** in /etc/mongod.conf

```
$ mongo -u mongoUser -p User123#@! --authenticationDatabase trackuser
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2015-07-16T14:44:54.741+0200 E QUERY    Error: 18 Authentication failed.
    at DB._authOrThrow (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1266:32)
    at (auth):6:8
    at (auth):7:2 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1266
exception: login failed
```

What to do in this case?? Same version Working in Mac but not in Ubuntu??

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding new parameter for DB name like this

```
-d trackuser
```

right now i guess you are using

`--authenticationDatabase trackuser`